# group_by: different behavior mutate and summarize

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with revenue numbers for different clients in different years. I want to calculate the total revenue for a client in a year. Then I want to calculate the mean of yearly revenue for the 3 highest grossing years.

I manage to do this with group_by and summarize. However in this way I "lose" all variables not used in grouping or calculation functions. I changed summarize to mutate but for one reason or another, this gives me different results.

Does anyone know why this happpens, or how to get same result in a different manner?

```
MASTERDATA%>%
  group_by(Client,Year)%>%
  summarise(Revenue=sum(Total, na.rm=TRUE))%>%
  slice_max(n=3,order_by=Revenue,with_ties = FALSE )%>%
  mutate(Revenue_top_3 = mean(Revenue))%>%
  select(Client,Year,Revenue)%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  distinct()
```

Applying this to the mtcars dataset

```
mtcars%>%
  group_by(gear,carb)%>%
  mutate(Revenue=sum(mpg, na.rm=TRUE))%>%
  slice_max(n=3,order_by=Revenue,with_ties = FALSE )%>%
  mutate(Revenue_top_3 = mean(Revenue))%>%
  select(gear,carb,Revenue)%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  distinct()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt you are not taking `mean` of 3 highest grossing years.

Here are two approaches -

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars%>%
  group_by(gear,carb)%>%
  summarise(Revenue=sum(mpg, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  slice_max(n=3,order_by=Revenue,with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  summarise(Revenue_top_3 = mean(Revenue))

#   gear Revenue_top_3
#  <dbl>         <dbl>
#1     3          64.2
#2     4          98.1
#3     5          30.6
```

And with same output but one less step.

```
mtcars%>%
  group_by(gear,carb)%>%
  summarise(Revenue=sum(mpg, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  summarise(Revenue_top_3 = Revenue %>% sort %>% tail(3) %>% mean())
```

Comment: Indeed I did not include mean calculation, however if I just simply replace `summarise` with `mutate `my problem stays.

Comment: Well, yes that seems logical to me that it doesn't work with `mutate` because in `mutate` the same value (`sum`) is repeated multiple times and when you take `mean` of it, it will give different results. `mean(c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4))` is different from `mean(c(3, 4))`. You have not shown your expected output but if you want the original dataset back with an extra column of values you can just add `%>% left_join(mtcars, by = 'gear')` to the above answers.

Comment: Okay thanks! Sorry for the inconvenience.